# Can you use an Azure Function to trigger an Azure Logic App?

Tags: function, azure, cron, azure-logic-apps

The time triggers within Logic Apps aren't really specific enough to meet my scheduling requirements, but using the scheduler looks overly expensive for our needs.

I see that functions can use CRON for timed triggering, so wondered if functions can actually be used to call Logic Apps, and hence have the Logic Apps triggered by the CRON time schedules?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this should be possible. You can invoke the flow from an Azure Function. You will have to call the Logic App endpoint workflow from the Azure Function. To start with look at this blogpost: [Invoking Flows from another Logic App](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carlosag/2015/05/31/using-nested-azure-logic-apps-or-invoking-flows-from-another-logic-app/)

In your Azure function you can use HttpWebRequest or other mechanisms to call the Logic App endpoint.

Comment: Cheers - I'll take a look.

Answer (score 1):

Logic Apps support complex schedule just like Azure Scheduler, currently this is configurable only via code view, but will soon be available in designer. You can view the syntax [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/scheduler/scheduler-advanced-complexity).